# Changing scenes with StartCoroutine or Application.LoadLevel

Tags: unity-game-engine

When changing scenes in a Unity project, say, from a Menu Scene to a Main Scene by pressing a button, which one of the following would be a more sensible way:

```
Application.LoadLevel( ("mainScene") );

StartCoroutine( LoadLevel("mainScene") );
```

The code behind the button is either of the above, as well as a huge number of other methods to be implemented, so that is why I am wondering which one to use for changing scenes...

Comment: You mean `LoadLevelAsync` perhaps in your coroutine example? I'm not sure that there is much to say about "more sensible" given the absence of a clear description/scenario.

Comment: Thanks Bart. No, I don't mean `LoadLevelAsync` but exactly the second line in my question. I only came across it in a script, so I thought would it be a better method of loading a new scene; i.e. less expensive computationally, because on pressing a button to load my main scene, a number of other functions will also be called, so I would like the actual scene-loading to be the last thing, as a few other methods and algorithms will be invoked when the scene-change button is pressed. When would you use each of these two?

Comment: Nothing will be less computationally intensive. Loading a scene is loading a scene. The only choice there really is, is between blocking and non-blocking. I.e. if you want loading progress to be indicated and have some other aspects of your game still work while you're loading your new scene, you will need to load asynchronously. As for your second call there ... I'm not even sure that is something which will work.

Comment: Thank you Bart. Now I understand what you mean.

Comment: The second call will work only if he has a method called LoadLevel in the script, I usually make use of coroutines to load a level only when I need to simulate a "loading" time or as @Bart said, to run other processes before loading the new scene.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I just realized that I had missed the method and its IEnumerator def!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `StartCoroutine` is better imo because if you play a sound when you click a button and try to change the scene right away, the sound will be cut depending on how you configured the GameObjects and scripts that control sound.

This is the script I use. Note that I give 0.2 seconds for the sound to finish.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

    public class SceneLoader : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private AudioController audioController;

        void Start ()
        {
            audioController = GameObject.FindWithTag ("AudioController").GetComponent<AudioController> ();
        }

        public void LoadLevel (string sceneName)
        {
            audioController.PlayMenuClick ();
            StartCoroutine (LoadSceneAsync (sceneName));
        }

        private IEnumerator LoadSceneAsync (string levelName)
        { 
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.2f);
            Application.LoadLevel (levelName);
        }
    }
```