# Required namespace for private AudioController not found

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have included the following line in my code, but the `AudioController` is highlighted red, so I searched for the corresponding namespace, though it seems `UnityEngine` should suffice.

What else should I include to be able to use this?

```
private AudioController audioController;
```

Here is the full relevant code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;
using System.Collections;

public class MenuScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private AudioController audioController;

    void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad( this.gameObject );
    }

    void Start()
    {
        audioController = GameObject.FindWithTag("AudioController").GetComponent<AudioController> ();
    }

    public void LoadLevel( string sceneName )
    {
        audioController.PlayMenuClick();
        StartCoroutine( LoadSceneAsync( sceneName ) );
    }

    private IEnumerator LoadSceneAsync( string levelName )
    { 
        yield return new WaitForSeconds( 0.2f );
        Application.LoadLevel( levelName );
    }

    public void startSimulation()
    {
            LoadLevel( "mainScene" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean AudioController? Not AudioSource? Or AudioListener? And please show us the full relevant code.

Comment: Thanks Bart.  Added the code in an edit.  I thought I would need an `AudioController` variable to initialize and use.  Is this not correct?

Comment: Is this AudioController something you have written yourself? If so, could you show?

Comment: No, I have not written an audio controller. I learned this code by going through some examples online. Are you saying this way of coding is referring to a pre-programmed thing?

Comment: I'm saying that to the best of my knowledge there is no AudioController in Unity. If you picked that up from somewhere, show us where you got it from.

Comment: Here is the link to one of my own questions. I was trying to see what happens with his suggested code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31607194/changing-scenes-with-startcoroutine-or-application-loadlevel/31613277#31613277

Comment: Okay, AudioController is something he must have written himself. It's not something standard in Unity.

Comment: Thanks Bart. I will look up this subject to learn how I can use simple sounds when a button is pressed, etc...

Comment: All you really need is an AudioListener in your scene (attached to your camera for example) and then an AudioSource with your button sound. It has a `Play()` method you can trigger to play the sound.

Comment: Perfect, thank you...